# How can I change the path of calendar views?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I use the [calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module and the views come with it.

**What I want is:** When my url is `http:mysite/2015` display the year view and when my url is `http:mysite/2015/03` display the month view (March of 2015). Of course the day same as well `http:mysite/2015/03/16`.

I try to change the path and contextual filters setting but I can't do that.
I'm sure it is a simple thing but I can't find the answer yet.

Comment: what url change you want ? Can you please tell in detail ?

Comment: normally my year view's path is "/year" and the contextual filter default value setting is "current date". When i go to http:mysite/year current year is open.. and with navigation i can go to forward or backward like "http:mysite/year/2014".. what i want is "http:mysite/2015 - http:mysite/2014"